# Facebook Tab height?

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to make a php file display on a Facebook Tab, very new to this, not quiet sure where to start, I've looked around the internet and not quiet found anything but Static HTML, and i need something more durable that allows the page to expand automatically depending what php page has been selected, i.e one might be 1000px and another might be 1500px but in the code it needs to automatically adjust the size now I've seen tabs work like that but looking for advice,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use percents values in your CSS for the height.

Comment: Ive done that but, it keeps loading at the bottom and getting bigger and bigger but its not really 100% it just keeps loading more, i want something instant like the rest?